# Firebase on Symfony4

Tags: php, firebase, symfony4

I use Firebase on my Symfony application.So, I install kreait/firebase-bundle but I don't know which file I can configure this bundle on symfony4.

This configuration:

```
kreait_firebase:

    connections:
    main:
    host: 
    secret: 
    references:
      users:
```

Which file I can use this configuration??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the [documentation packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/kreait/firebase-bundle) you can configure your settup in :

config/packages/firebase.yaml

thanks :)